# Finding a 12 V Peltier module that reaches less than 0 °C on the cold side

Tags: peltier

I am making a small cooler box using a Peltier. At first, I used a Tec1-12706 without researching first, and it barely went under 12 °C at the cold side. I need a Peltier module that is 40 mm x 40 mm that is 12 V that goes to at least under 0 °C. I have looked at ~ 20 modules, but no matter what, none tell you how cold it can get. It just says Q<sub>MAX</sub> that just says at what voltage it is when it is the coolest, but never say temperature.

How can I find a Peltier module that matches my specifications when it is not listed in the datasheet? Can I convert it from some other parameter?

Comment: Won’t the lower temperature be limited by the ambient ? And the delta is fixed?

Comment: Asking why your peltier module isn't getting as cold as you'd like is OK.  Asking where to buy a better module isn't. (Check the site rules - recommendations for parts or where to purchase them are off topic.). If you delete the request for a recommendation, the rest is OK.  You already have an answer explaining the cause of your problems.

Comment: @JRE Just when you wrote that comment I was busy removing the problematic part, sorry! :)

Comment: @pipe: No problem. Its a better question now, and Erik also know why.  So, all good.

Comment: I reached -40°C with the module you mentioned, just needs the right cooling off the hot side

Answer (score 5):

They can't tell you how cold it can get because that is a function of how much you are trying to cool, and the difference (Delta T) between the inside (cold side) and the outside (ambient) air temp.

Also how well the 2 sides are insulated from each other. That is how good the insulation of the cooler box.

The Q is how efficient the module is at doing its job of cooling. If you have a small space to cool, and the external heat sink is exposed to a cool day as opposed to hot, you will get a much lower internal temperature.

The Peltier you purchase may not come with a fan. If not,
be sure to include one to cool the heat sink. You will get poor efficiency without one.

The better the cooling of the external heatsink, the lower your inside will go.

Answer (score 0):

Also having a small heat sink on the cold side and a much larger heat sink on the hot side with a decent temperature controlled fan that blows harder when hotter. The small heat sink on the cold side with wide spacing between the fins will increase the surface area of the cooling side and allow a ice film to build up on the small inner heat sink and keep the ice box colder more efficiently.